# Singly Linked List C++: Head pointer does not connect to next node

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

For my assignment, I have to create a singly linked list and insert 3 items. I tried using an object oriented approach instead of the purely pointer method that my teacher and almost everyone else uses; head and tail are both nodes and attributes of my list class. The only issue with my code is that the head node's pointer does not update to the next node. Can anyone help me correct this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class node
{
public:
    int element;
    node* ptr;
    friend class list;
};



class list
{
public:
    //Including head and tail attributes and making them public so that 
they are easily accessible to anyone using the linked list construction
    node head;
    node tail;

    list()
    {
        head.element = -1; //-1 is sentinel value
        tail.element = -1;
        head.ptr = NULL;
        tail.ptr = NULL;
        head = tail;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return((head.ptr == NULL) && (head.element == -1));
    }

    void insert(int a)
    {
        if(empty())
        {
            head.element = a;
            tail.element = a;
        }

        else
        {
            //Making a new unnamed node, inserting the new value, and 
updating the tail attribute
            node* v = new node;
            tail.ptr = v;
            v -> element = a;
            v -> ptr = NULL;
            tail.element = v-> element;
            tail.ptr = v -> ptr;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        int i = 0;
        node *pointer = head.ptr;
        while(pointer != NULL)
        {
            cout << "The " << i+1 << "th element is: " << pointer -> 
element;
            pointer = pointer -> ptr;
            i++;
        }
    }

};



int main()
{
    int values[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    list lst;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        lst.insert(values[i]);
    }

    cout << lst.head.element << endl;
    cout << lst.tail.element;
    lst.print();

};
```

Comment: "head" and "tail" are both complete lists in the way that you construct them. You only append to tail and only read from head.

Comment: Classes and member functions by themselves don't make your program object-oriented; in C++ OO is normally expeessed with *inheritance* and *virtual functions*.

Comment: Also note that your code contains gratuitious special cases. An empty list doesn't have elements; introducing one with a special "sentinel" value requires more checks and makes your code more complicated, more error-prone, and less generic. You may get a lowered mark for this.

Comment: Also bear in mind that using a debugger is an absolutely essential skill for doing any serious programming, and it is not rocket science either. If you don't know how to use a debugger, I suggestvl you start learning this skill.

Comment: @nm Thank you for your input! Actually, the list class can access the attributes from the node class; using a friend class construct rather than direct inheritance was recommended to us by our professor. Additionally, I'm sure I could rewrite my if conditions without a sentinel value, it just made it immediately easier. Lastly, I use CLion on a Mac, and it comes with a debugger (though apparently it didn't quite point out the error). Can you recommend a better debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The head and tail nodes should remain as dummy nodes and not made part of the list. The element values of head and tail nodes do not need to be initialized or checked. An insert sequence for a non-empty list is

```
        // ...
        v->ptr = head.ptr; 
        head.ptr = v;
        // ...
```

See if you can fix the rest of the code.

If you create an append function, an append sequence for a non-empty list is

```
        // ...
        v->ptr = NULL;
        tail.ptr->ptr = v;
        // ..
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I actually wanted to make head and tail  nodes because it would make the insertion algorithm run in O(1) time; if the tail element is known and constantly updated, there is no need to parse through the list every time I would want to add an element, which would take O(n) time. But your comment did help me think about how I should update the pointers.

Comment: @arnavlohe15 - just to be clear, "insert" implies that the new node goes at the front of the list, or it can imply the new node is inserted into a sorted list at the proper location. "append" implies that the new node goes at the end of the list. Alternative terms for this are "push_front" for putting the new node at the start of the list, and "push_back" for putting the new node at the end of the list.

Comment: Oh, I see the difference. The assignment was to add new elements to the end of the list, in which case I should redefine insert() to append()